# Glympse API - PreSet a Nick Name

Tags: glympse

I want to preset the nickname of the sender which will be shown at the receiver's end while sending the **Glympse Ticket**.

Issue :- **When first time the sender is sending a Glympse it asks for Saving and Sending with a nick name, rather I have already set a nick name with the code detailed below.**

```
GGlympseLite glympse = GlympseLiteWrapper.instance().getGlympse();
        glympse.setNickname(DCCApplication.session.getName());
```

While the above code works fine from the second time onwards, but it asks for the Nick Name when the user is sending the Glympse for First Time, and it asks for the nickname everytime till the User has entered once in that popup.

Please let me know why is it so?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code for setting the nickname is perfect, but there is one very recent change in our SDK that is causing it to not set properly. The Glympse platform must be synchronized with the server before calling setNickname(). This change is mentioned under 2.6.54 in our change log:

https://developer.glympse.com/Content/client/full/android/guides/Glympse_Api_Android_Changelog.html

Implement GListenerLite as specified here:

[Glympse API - Handle Send Ticket Operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22006592/glympse-api-handle-send-ticket-operation/22077858#22077858)

And listen for the LC.EVENT_SYNCED event.

```
@Override public void eventsOccurred(GGlympseLite glympse, int event, Object param1, Object param2)
{
    if (0 != (event & LC.EVENT_SYNCED))
    {
        Log.d("", "Synced with server");
        GlympseLiteWrapper.instance().getGlympse().setNickname(DCCApplication.session.getName());
    }
}
```