# Glympse API - Handle Send Ticket Operation

Tags: glympse

I want to allow the application to call some method when the User Actually sends the Glympse Ticket

In simple terms I just want to get that is there any method to know whether the user has sent the Glympse after opening the Wizard or he/she has cancelled the wizard.

I have to do some operations when the user selects send Glympse Button

Looking forward for your valuable reply.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to call a method when the user has sent a Glympse is to register an event listener with the Glympse platform.

Here is an excerpt from the Glympse Send Lite demo showing how to do this:

```
// Start up the Glympse API
GlympseLiteWrapper.instance().start(this);

// Register this class as a listener for Glympse events
GlympseLiteWrapper.instance().getGlympse().addListener(this);
```

The parameter passed to addListener must be a class that implements GListenerLite. As a class using this interface, you will need to have an eventsOccured method.

```
@Override public void eventsOccurred(GGlympseLite glympse, int event, Object param1, Object param2)
{
    if (0 != (event & LC.EVENT_TICKET_CREATED))
    {
        Log.d("", "Ticket created");
        onTicketCreated((GTicketLite) param1);
    }
}
```

The LC.EVENT_TICKET_CREATED event sounds like what you are interested in capturing. You can create a method such as onTicketCreated() to do things in response to a ticket being created.